# IntelliJ 14 Ultimate - Can not add framework

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Why can I not add the maven framework to my module?
[image]

Comment: Is the maven plugin enabled? You can check it from `Settings -> Plugins`. See if `Maven Integration` is checked.

Comment: @Mustafa Just checked, it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is not considered as a framework in IntelliJ. If you want to add Maven support to your project, you should open the parent `pom.xml`, which will reimport the project as a Maven project.

See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-maven-model.html) for further detail.

> ## To import a Maven project with default settings
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose File | Open.
> 2. In the dialog box that opens, select the desired pom.xml file, and click OK. In this case the import is performed automatically, with the settings defined in the Maven Integration dialog.

Comment: That is false, asked my friend to check. Works fine for him: http://i.imgur.com/sgSrF1S.png

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Im trying to convert a non-maven project to a maven project. Not import an existing maven project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't configure frameworks in IntelliJ unless the configuration files are present, so if you don't have (yet) any `pom.xml`, I don't think it will work.

Answer (score -1):

File > Settings > Plugins > Search for Maven and check Maven Integration.

Now when you right-click your solution and add framework support you should see Maven listed

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiBDY.png)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP already stated that Maven Integration is enabled.